# Trying to put json into raw sql query and getting "Input string was not in a correct format"

Tags: c#, json, postgresql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

So, I using postgresql and need to update some 'jsonb' field and trying to do this with plain sql query, but it's a bit tricky when I trying to make this using interpolated strings or plain strings.

When I use json object serrialization code is working:

```
await _ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync($"UPDATE \"PropertyItems\" SET \"_media\" = {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { })}::jsonb");
```

but, when I trying to set json structure manually it's fails

```
var buf = $"UPDATE \"PropertyItems\" SET \"_media\" = '{{}}'::jsonb";  //fail
var buf = $"UPDATE \"PropertyItems\" SET \"_media\" = {{}}::jsonb";    //fail
var buf = $"UPDATE \"PropertyItems\" SET \"_media\" = \'{{}}\'::jsonb"; //fail
await _ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(buf);
```

I'm kind of curious why it's happen and is there still a way to make this working with only strings, without json serializations?

Comment: Wouldn't you just set it to null for an empty object? Or {} and not {{}}? Just been jumping through some hoops with the DevArt \ EntityFramework libs. "" won't work, neither will whitspace, you have to actually set the field to null. But if you use pgAdmin it will accept: {}, "{}", "", but not {{}}. <Shrug>

Comment: Empty object it's just for a shortness. This was enough to replicate the problem. In my case I have a bit more complex object however the problem is identical

Comment: Hmm, for what it's worth something else I found was that Postgres was happy with {"i":1} but barfed on {i:1} - you had to have the quotes around the field name.

Comment: because it's interpolated string. This is important for my example. However even escaping $ and using {} instead of {{}} still not working

Comment: I really think {{}} is not a valid JSON object - if I open a new JSON file in Visual Studio it's OK with {} but not with {{}}. And if I try a SQL query I can update a JSONB field with '{}'::jsonb but not '{{}}'::jsonb.

Comment: @AdamBenson let me know how you put {} inside interpolated string in C#

Comment: @silent_coder Use parameterized queries instead constructing sql queries by string concatenation or formatting. SQL injection is only one of the problems caused by this. *Quoting and Conversion errors* are the other two problems. That's what happens here

Comment: @silent_coder the other problem is that the first snippet probably *doesn't* use string interpolation. A very controversial feature of EF Core 2.0 is that it uses the same mechanism used by string interpolation to construct parameterized queries. In the second snippet though you are using plain-old string formatting with all the problems. By moving the `$"UDPATE..."` code to a different line you exposed yourself to all the problems of string concatenation

Comment: @silent_coder specifically, when you write `$"...{whatever}"` C# doesn't perform the formatting step at runtime. It creates a Formattable object with placeholders whose values come from whatever is inside `{}`. At runtime, EF Core takes this Formattable and constructs a parameterized query, with values created by executing the code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Indeed. You right. Could you please write a solid answer? I will accept it as answer to the question and it will helps other to save their time.

Comment: @silent_coder can you try with `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("UPDATE \"PropertyItems\" SET \"_media\" = {0}::jsonb",JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject));`? That's the syntax for parameterized queries in EF Core. I'm not sure if including `::jsonb` in the string will work, or if you need to write `\"media\" = {0}`. This will send the json string as a string parameter to the query

Comment: @silent_coder I don't have Postgres installed on my machine so I can't check the code to post an answer right now

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, it's works if written that way. So I confirming it's the problem related for Formattable/string confusing

Comment: @silent_coder <blush> yes, see your point.